# Multiple internal sensors of same 'type'

Tags: android, sensors, sensormanager

Android's SensorManager class will return a list of Sensors of a specified type. I am wondering if a device had, for example, multiple internal temperature sensors (TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE), how might I distinguish between them? Would Sensor.getName() and Sensor.getVendor() be all that I would have to work with?

Answer (score 1):

you can `getSensorList` to get to all sensors of a certain type but then you have to use those [methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html) you mentioned if you want a certain sensor.

even the implementation of `getDefaultSensor` just returns the first from the list

```
public Sensor getDefaultSensor(int type) {
     // TODO: need to be smarter, for now, just return the 1st sensor
     List<Sensor> l = getSensorList(type);
     return l.isEmpty() ? null : l.get(0);
}
```